# is it possible to get buyer's address while using PayPal's Checkout PHP SDK?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have this code for processing PayPal payments on my website :

```
$environment = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment(PAYPAL_ID, PAYPAL_SECRET);

$client = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient($environment);
$authorizationId = $_POST['authorizationId'];

$request = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Payments\AuthorizationsGetRequest($authorizationId);
$authorizationResponse = $client->execute($request);
$orderId = $authorizationResponse->result->supplementary_data->related_ids->order_id;

$request = new OrdersGetRequest($orderId);
$orderResponse = $client->execute($request);

var_dump($orderResponse->result->payer->address);
```

When I var_dump the address sdtObject I get only this

```
  public 'address' => 
    object(stdClass)[74]
      public 'country_code' => string 'FR' (length=2)
```

I am trying to get the buyer's shipping information after completing the order to store their address in my database because they are buying as a "guest".

That happens even when you pay with Card option of PayPal although they ask you to put in your shipping address.

The order is created like this

```
$order = json_encode([
                'purchase_units' => [
                    [
                        'description' => 'some desc...',
                        'items'       => array_map(function ($product) {
                            return [
                                'name'        => $product['name'] . " (n°" . $product['num'] . " | " . strtoupper($product['language']) . ")",
                                'quantity'    => $_SESSION['cart'][$product['id']],
                                'unit_amount' => [
                                    'value'         => number_format((float)$product['price'], 2, '.', ''),
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                ]
                            ];
                        }, $products),
                        'amount'      => [
                            'currency_code' => 'USD',
                            'value'         => $total > 200 ? $total : $total + 8,
                            'breakdown'     => [
                                'item_total' => [
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value'         => $total
                                ],
                                'shipping' => [
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value'         => $total > 200 ? '0.00' : '8.00',
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

And is then passed like this to the PayPal's JS SDK :

```
paypal.Buttons({
                    createOrder: (data, actions) => {

                        return actions.order.create(<?= $order; ?>);

                    },
                    onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
                        const authorization = await actions.order.authorize()
                        const authorizationId = authorization.purchase_units[0].payments.authorizations[0].id
                        const response = await fetch('<?= base_url('cart/process'); ?>', {
                            method: 'post',
                            headers: {
                                'content-type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                authorizationId
                            })
                        })
                        let responseText = await response.text();
                        $('.site-content').html(responseText);
                    },
                    onCancel: function(data, actions) {
                        alert("Order cancelled successfully!");
                    },
                    onError: function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The intent of the order which is created is `authorize`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You don't show details of how the order is created. Is this `intent:authorize` or `intent:capture` ? For what purpose are you doing an orders get request? Is it your intention to get shipping information before completing the order (to show a review page?) , or after completing the order?

Comment: @PrestonPHX Oh yes, I forgot to mention that the command was created with ``intent:capture``. I am trying to get the buyer's shipping information after completing the order to store their address in my database because they are buying as a "guest".

Comment: If you are using intent:capture , the word "authorization" should not appear anywhere in your code. Additionally, you should be doing an order capture call and the capture response will contain the shipping address in the purchase unit array.

Comment: You also should not be using the JS SDK's actions.order.create (client side create) in conjunction with the PayPal Checkout SDK. Create the order with PHP, and call it from the approval flow with https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: @PrestonPHX My bad, I'm stupid. I'm indeed using ``intent:authorize``. So what you saying is that if I do
```
$request = new AuthorizationsCaptureRequest($authorizationId);
$captureResponse = $client->execute($request);
```
the ``$captureResponse`` would contain the shipping address?

Comment: No, the AuthorizationsCaptureRequest is a Payments API call. That's something you'll do later (to capture the Authorization), since you're choosing to get an authorization (intent:authorize). Focus on the Order at checkout time. You need to authorize the Order after it's been approved by the payer.

Comment: @PrestonPHX Uhm.. I don't really understand how to get the shipping address and which Class of the PayPal's PHP SDK I need to call for that. I followed this [tutorial](https://grafikart.fr/tutoriels/paypal-checkout-standard-962) but it doesn't says anything about getting the shipping address of the buyer so I tried to find by myself with the PayPal's documentation but I can't get it right... What I understood is that with using ``intent=authorize`` the buyer authorize the seller to approve the order by "capturing" the order is that correct?

Comment: Approve is not the word to use there. Capturing an authorized order is a step that happens later. First you need to authorize the order to begin with, which is a step you are missing. The authorize response will contain the purchase_unit array with the shipping and other detials.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I authorize the response with ``$request = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Payments\AuthorizationsGetRequest($authorizationId);`` and I get the ``purchase_unit`` array but I don't have the shipping address although I get for example the email, full name, etc. of the buyer. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't know but since I can't see a log of that entire authorization response it's hard to offer comment. The order creation request and response could also be relevant (which as I mentioned should be done from PHP, not client side actions.order.create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$orderResponse` contains the shipping address : `print_r($orderResponse->result->purchase_units[0]->shipping->address);`

I was using `var_dump();` which when the item is too far from the main one puts "..." :
[image]

Because of that the only `address` array/object I found was in the `$authorizationResponse` but it would of contain only the `country_code`.